# Wordpress Archive page fails to load

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a problem which is now maddening me indeed! I have created an archive.php page in my theme, I have made two conditions. One for the title and one for the main loop. But the browser fails to load the page and errors "Problem Loading the Webpage". What should I do? Please help me. Here is my archive.php code:
(the main problem is the second loop/condition that is happening inside div#posts-wrapper, because when I remove that, the page works.)

```
<?php

/*
|   This is the cateogry page that when a user clicks on a category.
|    This file is for the Behdis Marketing Group Wordpress Theme
*/
?>
<?php
    get_header();
?>
<div class='grid-container' style='background-color: #FFF; border: 2px #CCC solid; padding-bottom: 50px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;'> <!-- Body section -->

                <div class='grid-100 grid-parent height-auto'> <!-- Bodt-container -->

                    <aside id='left_sidebar' class='grid-20  height-auto'> <!-- Left sidebar -->
                    <?php
                        // including left sidebar                       
                        get_sidebar('left');
                    ?>            
                    </aside><!-- End of left sidebar -->


                    <div id='center_column' class='grid-60 height-auto'><!-- End of center bar -->
                    <!-- this includes slideshow as well as six others thumbnails at the bottom of slideshow frame -->
                        <div class='archive-page-title font-nazanin dir-right'>
                        <?php
                            if ( have_posts() )
                            { 
                                if( is_tag() ) 
                                 { 
                                     $title = ('Tag Posts:  ' . single_tag_title('', FALSE));
                                     echo create_h1($title);
                                 }

                                 if( is_category() ) 
                                 { 
                                     $title = ('Cateogry Posts:  ' . single_cat_title('', FALSE));
                                     echo create_h1($title);
                                  }         
                            }
                            ?>
                         </div> 
                         <div id='posts-wrapper' class='archive-page-posts-wrapper font-nazanin dir-right margin-auto'>
                        <?php                           
                            rewind_posts();
                             if ( have_posts() )
                            { 
                            while(have_posts() )
                            {
                                         if( is_tag() ) 
                                         { 
                                             create_post(true, 'each-post-article');
                                         }                             
                                         if( is_category() ) 
                                         { 
                                             create_post(true, 'each-post-article');
                                          }  
                            }
                            }

                            ?>
                         </div> 
                    </div><!-- End of center bar -->

                    <aside id='right_sidebar' class='grid-20 height-auto'><!-- End of right sidebar -->                                     
                    <?php
                        get_sidebar('right');
                    ?>
                    </aside><!-- End of right sidebar -->

                </div><!-- End of body-container -->

</div><!-- End of body section -->
<!-- End of basic template              
<?php
    get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: don't use `if ( have_posts() )` and then `while(have_posts() )`, you just need `while(have_posts() )` because if you dont have any posts, the loop is never entered, which is i think what you are trying to accomplish with the if statement. the extra if makes you skip the first post.

Comment: I have checked what you recommended, but still fails. Is is ok that if I use two while statement one after the other?

Comment: using 2 while statements should be fine since you use rewind_posts();. my comment was more of a nitpick, sorry, I don't why your code is not working.

Comment: Still it does not work, it goes into an infinite loop and the browser crashes

Comment: @SethCohen I've always wondered about that, though [the Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Using_The_Loop) shows the standard loop using the `if` .. `while` structure.  @Mostafa - what's `create_post()` do?  Does the code work if you replace it with an echo statement (just to test)?  Any errors in your PHP logs?

Comment: No Ur right I misspoke

Comment: No, there is no error. When I replace create_post with the_content it does not work. When I replace it with the_excerpt it does not still, but ONLY and ONLY when I use echo get_the_content it works'

Comment: very strange problem. Even I changed the whole structure, have used a new one, a standard one, copied from a standard theme, but still the above issue remains. the_content, the_excerpt fail and only get_the_content works

Comment: Oh, the problem found! A plugin caused this. Very strange. Because I always checks plugin-intervention first and then post the issue here, but this plugin is super-famous and very much proved I never though it could cause such issue. thanks all the lad..thanks\